# Skype EULA pops up at every startup

Tags: skype

Everytime I boot my computer, Skype starts automatically after login. The problem is two fold:
* it keeps asking me to accept the licence agreement
* it keeps forgetting my password

That's quite annoying. Does anyone have any idea of where the problem might be coming from? It's been like that for a while, but I can't pinpoint when it started exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skype holds its settings in a hidden folder `~/.Skype`.

Possibly you have the wrong permissions or possible corruption in the files the application uses.

Try renaming this folder.  Then re-add your login details and retest closing and reopening the application.

In a terminal

```
mv ~/.Skype ~/.Skype_backup
```

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem, Skype was forcing my to re-accept EULA and was forgetting my settings e.g. whether I wanted pop-ups or not.

The EULA problem was corrected by removing the shared.xml in the .Skype folder:

```
$ cd ~/.Skype
$ rm shared.xml
```

The settings problem was corrected by removing the config.xml in my user's folder under .Skype e.g. if my user is pinocchio

```
$ cd ~/.Skype/pinocchio
$ rm config.xml
```

Restarted Skype all is well with the world again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the problem was that config.xml was owned by root.

The solution was easy :

```
sudo chown user:user ~/.Skype
```

change user to your login name (you can find it by typing :

```
echo $USERNAME
```