# Skype resets and forgets password, EULA signing after reboot

Tags: 12.04, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skype EULA pops up at every startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99229/skype-eula-pops-up-at-every-startup)

I have Xubuntu 12.04 running on a MacBook Air 4,1. I use Skype (installed via downloading the .deb and `sudo dpkg -i <skype>.deb` (it's the Ubuntu 10.4 64bit version). Everytime I reboot, Skype starts by showing the End User License Agreement. If I hit "Agree", I see my Skype Name but I still have to put in the password (although before the reboot, I set it to be remembered). Needless to say, That's quite tedious. I also tried `rm ~/.Skype/<myskypename>/profile*.dbb`, but that did not help.

Comment: Okay, I found it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/99229/skype-eula-pops-up-at-every-startup